# Request only messaging with direct-vm in camel routes

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

How can we process direct-vm asynchronously?

I have the following Camel routes definition:

```
<route id="routeA">
<from uri="activemq:queue:queueA" />
<to uri="direct-vm:someProcessing" />
<to uri="direct-vm:processAsync" />
</route>

<route id="routeB">
<from uri="direct-vm:processAsync">
<threads executorServiceRef="someRef">
 <inOnly uri="direct-vm:timeTakingRoute" />
<threads>
<route>
```

When queue consumer consumes message and sends to routeB and calls `direct-vm:timeTakingRoute` using threads DSL, caller thread which is `queueA` still waits until thread created using thread DSL completes.

How can we process this asynchronously (Caller thread should not wait until thread created using thread DSL completes)?

Answer (score 3):

Direct component is designed to be synchronous http://camel.apache.org/direct-vm.html

Please try to use **seda** instead:

```
<route id="routeA">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:queueA" />
    <to uri="direct-vm:someProcessing" />
    <inOnly uri="seda:processAsync" />
</route>

<route id="routeB">
    <from uri="seda:processAsync" />
    <to uri="direct-vm:timeTakingRoute" />
</route>
```

Comment: Thank you, I too thought the same. I have seen a ticket to make direct-vm async. By using vm or seda a thread always listens for request and trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You can either choose `seda` or `vm` component.
When using seda, note that queues are only visible within a it's CamelContext.
If you want inter-communication between `CamelContext`, use `vm` component, which is an extension to `seda` component. 
Read more: [seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) [vm](http://camel.apache.org/vm.html)

Comment: Thank you, I too thought the same. I have seen a ticket to make direct-vm async. By using vm or seda a thread always listens for request and trying to avoid that.